# Не удается подключится к postgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

У меня такой код подключения к posrtgreSQL в Python
Выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'connection' is not defined
Подскажите, где я не прав?

```
try:
    with psycopg2.connect(host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name,
        port=port) as connection:

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
            print(f"Server version: {cursor.fetchone()} ")
        connection.close()
        print('[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')

except Exception as _ex:
    print('[INFO] Error while working with postgreSQL', _ex)


[INFO] Error while working with postgreSQL 
[INFO] Error while working with postgreSQL
```

Comment: Скорее всего возбуждается исключение при попытке создать подключение. Интерпретатор попадает в блок finally, а переменная connection ещё не была создана. Что возбуждает NameError

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал больше использовать `with`, хотя там есть некоторые тонкости, посмотрите https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement,
А имеющийся простой пример записал бы так:

```
import psycopg2
try:
    with psycopg2.connect("тут все параметры...") as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
            print(f"Server version: {cursor.fetchone()} ")
        connection.close()
        print('[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')

except Exception as _ex:
    print('[INFO] Error while working with postgreSQL', _ex)
```

UPD: Более корректный вариант предложил @Alpensin, только там не понятно, куда вставить `print` про закрытие, чтобы он был выведен точно после закрытия :)

```
import psycopg2
from contextlib import closing

try:
    with closing(psycopg2.connect()) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
            print(f"Server version: {cursor.fetchone()} ")

except Exception as _ex:
    print('[INFO] Error while working with postgreSQL', _ex)
```

Comment: Только если мы используем контекстный менеджер, то нет смысла закрывать соединение вручную.

Comment: @Alpensin ну я по ссылке на документацию как-то иначе понял.

Comment: Вы правы. Пока разбирался еще нашел удобный универсальный контекстный менеджер для подобных объектов, которые не закрываются автоматически по выходу из конекста https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing